# Additive series expression of Dedekind zeta functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, notation, terminology, algebraic-number-theory

The Riemann zeta function is defined as:
$$
\zeta(s) := \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s}
$$
for all $s$ in the $\textrm{Re}(s)>1$ half-plane.

In order to distinguish between $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s}$ and the Euler product expression of $\zeta$, I usually refer to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s}$ as the *Dirichlet series expression* of $\zeta$.

The same applies for Dirichlet $L$-series:
$$
L(\chi,s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\chi(n)}{n^s}.
$$
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\chi(n)}{n^s}$ is the Dirichlet series expression of the Dirichlet $L$-series $L(\chi,s)$ (again, as distinct from the Euler product expression).

Now we come the the Dedekind zeta function, defined in terms of some algebraic number field $K$:
$$
\zeta_K(s) := \sum_{\mathfrak{a}}\frac{1}{N(\mathfrak{a})^s},
$$
where the sum is taken over all integral ideals $\mathfrak{a} \subset \mathcal{O}_K$, and $N$ denotes the ideal norm in $\mathcal{O}_K$.

My question is: What do we call $\sum_{\mathfrak{a}}\frac{1}{N(\mathfrak{a})^s}$? Note that it is not a Dirichlet series.

Might we call it the *additive series expression* (again, as distinct from the Euler product expression)?

Any suggestions, or does anyone know of a universally accepted standard name for it?

Many thanks.

Comment: It can be viewed as a Dirichlet series if you group $N(\cdot)=n$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z^+$.

Comment: I don't see there being much difficulty in calling it a "Dirichlet series" (particularly if the terms are regrouped as suggested by Kemono Chen), though if you are concerned about this, perhaps "Dirichlet-type series" would do?  For comparison, the term "Dirichlet-type integral" is used in the text *Fractal Zeta Functions and Relative Fractal Drums* by Lapidus *et al.* to refer to integrals of the type $\int \varphi(x)^s\,\mathrm{d}\mu(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call it a "Dirichlet series indexed by the ideals of $K$" (really, by the "nonzero ideals of $\mathcal O_K$").

In a similar way, the product representation
$$
\zeta_K(s) = \prod_{\mathfrak p} \frac{1}{1 - 1/{\rm N}(\mathfrak p)^s}
$$
for ${\rm Re}(s) > 1$ is an "Euler product indexed by the primes of $K$" (really, by the "nonzero prime ideals of $\mathcal O_K$"). This should be distinguished from an Euler product over rational primes, which in this case would be
$$
\zeta_K(s) = \prod_{p} \frac{1}{Q_p(1/p^s)}
$$
for $Q_p(1/p^s) = \prod_{\mathfrak p\mid p} (1 - 1/{\rm N}(\mathfrak p)^s)$.  Over $\mathbf Q$, a function represented by a Dirichlet series or Euler product on some right half-plane has a unique such expression, but over a number field bigger than $\mathbf Q$ there are many different ideals (including different prime ideals) with the same norm, so a Dirichlet series or Euler product over a number field bigger than $\mathbf Q$ can arise in more than one way (it does not determine its coefficients).